# How to Rewrite url using RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I could not figure out why the rewrite rule is not working. I want to rewrite `localhost/admin/update.php?id=1` where id is dynamic based on the user I clicked to fetch the data from the database to `localhost/admin/update/1`

This is my attempted .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^update update.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^update/([0-9]+)$ update.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Which directory is the `.htaccess` containing these rules located in?

Comment: The same directory where the update,php is.....

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^update update.php [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^update/([0-9]+)$ update.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

You need to remove the first rule and ensure that MultiViews is disabled. Your first rule is blocking the second rule (and serves no purpose from the criteria stated in the question). For example:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^update/([0-9]+)$ update.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

This assumes the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/admin` subdirectory (as implied in comments).

> I want to rewrite `localhost/admin/update.php?id=1` where `id` is dynamic based on the user I clicked to fetch the data from the database to `localhost/admin/update/1`

Note that your *description* is completely the opposite of what the above directive does (and what you should be doing). This rule rewrites the request from `/admin/update/1` to `/admin/update.php?id=1`. You should be linking to `/admin/update/1` in your application.